# Why is normal reaction on a pulley not equal the weight hanging below it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Pulley and string are all massless => hence, I consider only the net downward force applied to the pulley by both the masses under gravity.

Why is the normal force on the pulley not equal to the net weight below it?
(considering the fact that it is a ideal pulley-string-mass system)

[image: FBD attached for better clarity]

Comment: If the masses were in uniform motion you'd be correct with $(m_1+m_2)g$, but are they? If they're accelerating, there are additional forces of the form mass $\times$ acceleration.

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98205/why-does-the-tension-on-the-pulley-in-an-atwood-machine-not-equal-m-1-m-2g

Answer (score 0):

> Why is normal reaction on a pulley not equal the weight hanging below it ?

Because the weights are accelerating, so the system of weights and pulley taken as a whole is not in equilibrium (assuming $m_1 \ne m_2$). The centre of mass of the system is accelerating downwards at an acceleration of

$\displaystyle a_{com} = \frac {m_2-m_1} {m_2+m_1} a = \frac {(m_2-m_1)^2} {(m_2+m_1)^2} g$

so for the system as a whole we have

$(m_2+m_1)g - N = (m_2+m_1)a_{com}
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow N = (m_2+m_1)(g-a_{com}) = \frac {4m_2m_1} {m_2+m_1} g < (m_2+m_1)g$

Note that, as expected, we have $N=2T$ because the pulley on its own *is* in equlibrium.